# Insert into table with auto-increment field

Tags: sql-server-2008, auto-increment

I have two tables called HRData and HRDataHistory. HRDataHistory has the same structure as HRData except the first column is an autoincrement field and the last column is a DateTime field.

HRData has a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [HR].[HRData_History]
ON [HR].[HRData]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS 
    INSERT INTO HR.HRDataHistory
    SELECT *, GETDATE() 
    FROM inserted
;

GO
```

This is working on an existing development machine. I am trying to mirror this relationship on my local sql server instance so that I can test some changes. Using SSMS I used 'Script Table as Create To...' and created the structure of each table and index on my local sql server instance. However when I do this for the trigger I get the following error:

```
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'HR.HRDataHistory' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

I know the preferred method would be to specify the columns, but I want to mirror production which does not currently do that and further I want to understand why it is working in production but not on my test database.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're trying to insert data into an `IDENTITY` column, which auto-populates itself whenever you insert another row in that table.

Off the top of my head, you can do something like below (although I believe there are more elegant solutions and **I do not guarantee that this is a safe solution, nor have I tried something like this and I recommend testing on a TEST database before trying in production/LIVE**):

- add another column to HRDataHistory table which does not have identity set on it (because you cannot remove identity form a colum once set), but must have the same datatype as the current ID (`IDENTITY`) column
- use a `UPDATE` query to move all of your ID's from your `IDENTITY` column to your new column:

  ```
  UPDATE HRDataHistory
  SET new_column = ID
  ```
- Drop the `IDENTITY` column (**but this might have grave implications if you have any FK set on it and possibly other objects that use it**):

  ```
  ALTER TABLE HRDataHistory
  DROP COLUMN ID
  ```
- Rename the "new_column" to the name of your previous `IDENTITY` column:

  ```
  EXEC sp_RENAME 'HRDataHistory.new_column' , 'ID', 'COLUMN'
  ```

At this point I believe you can use your trigger to "copy" the newly inserted data from the `HRData` table into the `HRDataHistory`, since the column names should match and there is no more conflict due to `IDENTITY`.

Again, this might (**not guaranteed**) work so **I recommend you first check on a TEST environment**.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to insert data into an identity column. On production, we are doing INSERT INTO HISTORY SELECT *,GetDate() FROM DATA but the same trigger won't work on dev despite the tables being identical.